# Induced-norm bound of composite operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be square real matrices with appropriate dimensions such that they do not commute. Generally, the following inequality does not hold.
$$\|ABx\|\leq\|B\|\|Ax\|$$

Is there any condition that makes it hold without assuming $AB=BA$?

Comment: What kind of condition do you have in mind? One can come up with all sorts of things which are unlikely to be of use to you. For example, this holds if $x \in \ker(A)$. Actually, are you wanting the inequality to hold for some specific $x$, or for all $x$? Another sufficient condition: if $A$ and $B$ are both isometries (i.e. preserve length), then your inequality holds, and in fact it becomes an equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to interpret your question as follows:

> **Question:** Under what conditions on $A$ and $B$ does $\|ABx\| \leq \|B\| \|Ax\|$ hold for all $x$?

I will work in the context of $n$-by-$n$ complex matrices, but everything works over the reals also.

> **Background:** Recall a matrix $A$ is called *Hermitian* if $A^*=A$, where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose. The spectrum of a Hermitian matrix real. A matrix is called *positive semi-definite* if $\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$. A matrix is positive-semidefinite if and only if it is Hermitian and has nonnegative spectrum. The sum of two positive semi-definite matrices is positive semi-definite. The latter fact leads to a well-defined partial ordering of Hermitian matrices given by $A \leq B$ if and only if $B-A$ is positive semi-definite. Every positive semi-definite matrix $A$ has a unique positive semi-definite square root $A^{1/2}$. The square root operation is order preserving: $A \leq B$ implies $A^{1/2} \leq B^{1/2}$. Note however that the squaring operation is *not* order preserving. For any matrix $A$, the matrix $A^*A$ is positive semi-definite, hence has a square-root $|A| := (A^*A)^{1/2}$ which is sometimes referred to as the *operator modulus*.

The main fact I want to use is the following.

> **Lemma:** Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices. Then, $\|Ax\| \leq \|Bx\|$ for all $x$ if and only if $|A|^2 \leq |B|^2$, with respect to the ordering on Hermitian matrices.

> **Proof:** \begin{align*} 
> && \|Ax\| \leq \|Bx\| \text{ for all } x \\
> & \Leftrightarrow & \langle Ax,Ax\rangle \leq \langle Bx,Bx\rangle \text{ for all } x \\
> & \Leftrightarrow & \langle  (|B|^2 - |A|^2)x,x\rangle \geq 0 \text{ for all } x \\
> & \Leftrightarrow & |B|^2 - |A|^2 \text{ is positive semi-definite} \\
> & \Leftrightarrow & |A|^2 \leq |B|^2 \text{ with respect to the ordering on Hermitian matrices}
> \end{align*}

A consequence of the above lemma is that, if $\|Ax\| \leq \|Bx\|$ for all $x$, then $|A| \leq |B|$ (by monotonicity of the square root). In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are positve-semidefinite, a necessary condition to get $\|Ax\| \leq \|Bx\|$ for all $x$ is to have $A \leq B$.

To get an answer to your question, we set $A$ equal to $AB$ and $B$ equal to $\|B\| A$ in the above lemma, which yields the following:

> **Corollary:** Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices. Then $\|ABx\| \leq \|B\| \|Ax\|$ for all $x$ if and only if $|AB|^2 \leq \|B\|^2 |A|^2$ with respect to the ordering on Hermitian matrices. In particular, onc necessarily has $|AB| \leq \|B\| |A|$.

Note that the similar looking, but distinct, condition $|AB|^2 \leq \|A\|^2 |B|^2$ is actually always satisfied. This is because $|A|^2 \leq \|A\|^2$ always holds, where the right hand side is interpreted as a multiple of the identity matrix, and the operation $X \mapsto B^*XB$ is an order-preserving map of the set of positive-definite matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much.